# Tesseract OCR Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path does not exist

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I am creating simple OCR app be following links. Everything I have done & now I'm trying to build/compile app but getting below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path does not exist!
```

My Code is :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ImageView imageView;
        private Bitmap bitmap;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.textimage);

            bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
            baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract/tessdata/eng.trainedata", "eng");

/* Also tried
     baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract/", "eng");
     baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract/tessdata/", "eng");
*/
            baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
            Log.v("....Text...", "....");
            String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
            Log.v("....Text...", " " + recognizedText);
            baseApi.end();
        }
    }
```

Error I'm getting :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ts.myapplicationtest1/com.ts.myapplicationtest1.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path does not exist!
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data path does not exist!
at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.init(TessBaseAPI.java:303)
at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.init(TessBaseAPI.java:280)
at com.ts.myapplicationtest1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Refer screenshot of my phone directory for data set :

[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0NYhe5T38-zMVJRaUQ5UHlmVUk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @rmthesis Could you please provide solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Datapath is set to the parent folder of `tessdata` folder, thus it should be `/mnt/sdcard/tesseract/`.